# Advantages of linq-to-xml compared to OfficeOpenXML.WordProcessing namespace

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml, openxml

I'm working on an application that needs to generate Word documents based on user input, database values and a template. I've looked online for examples, and found many different approaches to generate word documents but I've made up my mind and decided to stick with the official `Office Open XML SDK 2.5`. Now I've just written a simple program that inserts a table (stored in a .xml file) into a word document:

***Edit:*** *Question down at the bottom if not interested in the code*

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
XNamespace ns = XNamespace
    .Get(@"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main");
byte[] byteArray = File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:/Users/Alexander/Downloads/WordTest.docx");
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    XDocument xdoc;
    stream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

    using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(stream, true))
    {
```

Then I can do 2 different things which will generate the same output.

1) Using **OfficeOpenXml.Wordprocessing** namespace methods:

```
#region Openxml.WordProcessing

var paragraphs = doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.ToList();
Table tbl = new Table(File.ReadAllText(@"C:/users/alexander/downloads/tablecontent.xml"));
var bookmark = paragraphs.SelectMany(p => p.Descendants<BookmarkStart>()
                                           .Where(bm => bm.Id == "0")).FirstOrDefault();
doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.ReplaceChild(tbl, bookmark.Parent);

#endregion Openxml.WordProcessing
```

2) Using **Linq-To-XML**:

```
#region LINQ TO XML

XElement xtbl = XElement.Load(
   new FileStream(@"C:/users/alexander/downloads/tablecontent.xml", FileMode.Open));

using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(doc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(sr))
    xdoc = XDocument.Load(xr);

//Document - Body - Paragraphs - Runs/Bookmarks/etc. 
//any way to write this more clearly in linq-to-xml?
var test = xdoc.Elements().First().Elements().First().Elements()
               .SelectMany(e => e.Elements()).ToList();

var startBookmark = test.Where(p => p.Name == XName.Get("bookmarkStart", ns.NamespaceName) 
                 && p.Attribute(XName.Get("id", ns.NamespaceName)).Value == "0").First();

startBookmark.Parent.ReplaceWith(xtbl);

using (XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(doc.MainDocumentPart.GetStream()))
            xdoc.Save(xw);

#endregion LINQ TO XML
```

And finally I write the document to a new file:

```
using (FileStream fs = 
    new FileStream(@"C:/users/alexander/downloads/WordTestModified.docx", FileMode.Create))
{
    stream.WriteTo(fs);
}
```

As far as I see it, the first option is easier and the code is more clear to read, (no use of `XName` and no need for extra `StreamReader`/`XmlReader/Writer`) but are there any distinct advantages Linq-to-xml has over this approach? This is going to be a big application and I don't want to be limited later on.

Comment: For LINQ-to-XML, I suggest using `XDocument` - you can remove a bunch of the code and replace it with something like `XDocument xtbl = XDocument.Load(@"C:/users/alexander/downloads/tablecontent.xml");` and then when you're done modifying the XDocument, simply call `xtbl.Save();`.  No need to have all the streams and readers.

Comment: @Tim Only the table is xml though, I don't think I can do `XDocument.Load(...)` with a .docx file so I need the streams

Comment: You really should create a separate Question for the second question as it's a very different topic. Please do so and remove it from this question.

Comment: On the whole, Linq is probably going to execute faster than the Open XML SDK, which adds layers of abstraction. These make working with the Word "object model" more intuitive and more like using the "interop" object model, which, as you say, also makes the code easier to read.

Comment: @CindyMeister Thanks, I'm probably going to go with Open XML SDK to make the code more maintainable. For the Id's, I've been searching for ages again today and there isn't really a good way yet it seems... I'm just going to add a `SdtBlock` for every record in the database so I can match the `SdtBlockId` with Id in the database and fill in the ones I need. I don't think I have any better options really :/

Comment: As I said, ask it as a new question - the topic is too diverse and too different to cover in the same question. Trust me,  Word is my "home" :-)